# How can I make sure that input date format does not change with browser language?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website where some users have an American date format (mm/dd/yyyy) and others have a French one (dd/mm/aaaa), and maybe others have other formats (e.g. yyyy/mm/dd). Is there a way I can force an HTML input to have a specific date format? Or am I stuck with using `<input type="text">`?

Something like this
`<input type="date" format='dd-mm-yyyy'>`

I tried using `placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"` but it did not work